# django-extensions test_error_logging

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

When running the full set of tests for django i am getting this error:

```
FAIL: test_error_logging (django_extensions.tests.management_command.CommandTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/tests/management_command.py", line 35, in test_error_logging
    self.assertEqual(len(handler.messages['error']), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Can anyone explain why i might be getting this and how to stop it?

Comment: i can now make this test pass by also adding in the INSTALLED_APPS list 'django_extensions.tests' but that to me seems a bit ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is similar to this [issue](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/279) on the django-extensions github page.

Looks like the solution is to update to version 1.0.3

Comment: where would you put that, i dont think that is valid syntax for python

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to the django-extension project where the error was reported. Try updating to version 1.0.3 to see if the error is resolved.